# graphql-java variable mandatory (required) in programmatically created schema

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm new to GraphQL and graphql-java.
I'm trying to create this schema programmatically

```
type Query{name:String!}
```

I don't know how to make the `name` field not being null `String!`
By default this is optional.

```
GraphQLObjectType queryType = GraphQLObjectType.newObject()
        .name("Query")
        .field(GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition()
                .name("name")
                .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                .dataFetcher(new StaticDataFetcher("Joe")))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.type(GraphQLNonNull.nonNull(Scalars.GraphQLString))
```

Comment: This should definitely be in the documentation! 
https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/schema/